# Windows Phone 8 button too big

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, button, windows-phone-8, border

When I add a button control to blend I end up with the picture below. The layout of the button it's much bigger than it's border, but I can actually click the button if it's in the layout, even if the border is smaller.

That can really mess up the UX, because user can press button even if he shouldn't.
How can I fix this and make layout = border ?

I use Visual Studio 2012 and building windows phone 8 store C# project.

[image: Button]

Comment: It should also work if you set `Margin="-12"` (?), this way you dont need to change the template...

Comment: I think no, because that just changes the position of the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the additional touch-target overhang added to the control. It appears that you have placed a `RenderTransform` on the button which makes the overhang unnecessary. The easiest thing to do is:

1. Right-click the Button
2. Choose **Edit template** -> **Edit a copy**
3. Give the template a meaningful name

   - If you want to make the same changes in all buttons, choose **Apply to all**
4. In the template, you will see an item named `ButtonBackground` with a `Margin` of 12 (it will be highlighted green in the properties window, since it is bound to a resource
5. Click the little green button next to the `Margin` in the properties window and choose **Reset**
6. Enter whatever value you like